# How to stop Extent Report from trying to connect to MongoDB

Tags: selenium-extent-report, extentreports

After adding ExtentReport to a project, I get an error when it tries to connect to MongoDb. How does one tell ExtentReport not to attempt that connection?

Comment: If you are using ExtentXReporter only then you will see this. If you are not using ExtentX, do not use this reporter. Also there is a request for the dev of this library to silently ignore the connection.

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/944

Comment: Thank you. So, it tries to connect always, but it will be fixed so that it does not log an error is Mongodb is not there.

Comment: Yes. Once you attach this reporter then it will try to connect to both the app server and db. We have created a setting in our properties to externalize this.